# How to achieve synchronization in DB update when application is running on multiple nodes?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, synchronization, high-availability

I am new to J2EE development and trying to get some basics right. So the doubt is like, suppose I have an `employee` table somewhere in a database and a function which increases the `salary`column in `employee` table.

```
public synchronized IncreaseSalaryResponse increaseSalary(int empId, long raise);
```

In my case the service is running on two nodes (so two JVMs) for high availability. Now if two calls are made simultaneously to increase salary of an employee and in case they hit different hosts, the function call which gets over last shall have its effect reflected in the ultimate salary.

Does DB makes sure that such race conditions are avoided at its level?

If not, how to handle this situation in my case.

Please provide ideas.

Comment: I don't think that this can be handled at the application level.  You can make the update query in such a way that "update emp set salary = salary + increment where ..." rather than "update emp set salary=newsalary where.." .. This way, when two processes are trying to increment salary , the new value will be base salary + increment 1 + increment2.   Also when the first process updates the table with the salary value, the row will not be available for any other processes for update unless first process commits the changes.  Database handles concurrency by locking the changed row.

Comment: But what if both the queries read the current salary at the same time and add increment on it, resulting in final salary `currentSalary+raise1` or `currentSalary+raise2`.

Comment: You havent mentioned what database that you are using.  Oracle will not allow one row to be updated by two processes simultaneously.  You can open two sessions of the database and try to update same row in both the sessions. You can see that the second session will hang and wait for the first session to commit the changes

Comment: Then in case of Oracle your first argument of using `update emp set salary = salary + increment where ...` does not hold anymore. As even if I do `update emp set salary=newsalary where..` the second session would hang. So race condition would be avoided. And if it is the case then my question `Does DB makes sure that such race conditions are avoided at its level?` should have been answered with a `YES`.

Comment: Oracle way of handling your race condition is to time out the second attempt based on timeout value ( if the first process which has updated the row hasn't commited yet) which can be captured by your process and do take necessary steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the RDMS you are using if it is Transnational or not and the level of Isolation.

According to Wikipedia,

> Transactions in a database environment have two main purposes:
>
> 1- To provide reliable units of work that allow correct recovery from
> failures and keep a database consistent even in cases of system
> failure, when execution stops (completely or partially) and many
> operations upon a database remain uncompleted, with unclear status.
>
> 2- To provide isolation between programs accessing a database concurrently.
> If this isolation is not provided, the program's outcome are possibly
> erroneous.

Comment: Then as a developer what should be my area of concern. Is it just making sure that I am using application level locks when updating a shared resource e.g. a database table. Is rest taken care by the DB?

Comment: Also as I understand being transactional only means that a transaction will either be committed or rolled back completely. Isolation helps for my purpose. But on choosing isolation supporting DB could I be sure that race conditions will not occur?

Comment: You need to make sure that the database you are using supports transactions (by default all modern* RDBM's do). And you need to make sure you chose the appropriate isolation level. In JDBC for example, you can set the isolation level for all transaction issued on a specific connection. This article http://vladmihalcea.com/2014/12/23/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/ explains the topic in more details

Comment: Yes if you chose appropriate isolation levels, race conditions will not occur assuming that you have your application designed correctly for multithreaded access (i.e using synchronized).